# show that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n+x)=0$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f : \left[0,\infty\right]\to \mathbb R$ be uniformly continuous.

If $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n+x)=0$ where $x$ is in $[0,1]$  then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$

Furthermore if $f$ is just continuous , what happens to the result?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you please post some of your thoughts to approach the problem and we will be glad to give hints and comments.

Comment: Is this a limit over the natural numbers or over the reals?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro It is clear the interesting problem is a limit over the reals.

Comment: @Jacobo But the first limit is not over the reals?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Of course it is not. Again, it is clear that that is the interesting problem.

Comment: @Jacobo No need to be condescending; I'm just making this explicit for the record.

Answer (score 5):

You can consider the function $f$ that is zero everywhere except at the intervals $[n,n+1/n]$, where its graph forms isosceles triangles of hight $1$ with base on the $x$ axis. This gives a counterexample for the last problem.

To prove the first problem, let it be given any $e>0$ then there is $M>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<e/2$ whenever $|x-y|<1/M$.

Now $|f(x)|\leq|f(x)-f([x]+k/M)|+|f([x]+k/M)|$

Let $k$ be such that $[x]+k/M$ is closest to $x$. Then the first sumand above is $<e/2$, and the second term is less than $e/2$ for $[x]$ large enough.

Therefore $|f(x)|<e$ for $x$ large enough.

Comment: You seem to have a cyclic dependency in your choices of the lower bound for $x$ and for $k$. You choose $k$ based on $x$, then choose a lower bound for $x$ based on $k$ and hence $x$, so it is not clear that such a lower bound exists.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro It is only apparent. The order written is the order in which you think about it. Choose the other way around and there is no cycle. Notice that the choice of $x$ large only depends on the finitely many $k=1,2,...,M$.

Comment: The first choice, then, would be "$[x]$ large enough", which is to say, choose an $N$ such that $|f([x]+k/M)|\le\epsilon/2$ for $[x]\ge N$. But this has a dependence on $k$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro There are only finitely many $k$. So, that is not a problem.

Comment: Ah, you are using the integer-ness of $k$. You should make that explicit. (Is $M$ also an integer?)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes. The letters get less integer as they advance in the alphabet.

Comment: But that would mean that $e$ is more integer than $n$. Nevermind. The $e$ should be $\epsilon$.

Comment: @jacobo thanks but i dont understand why f(x)-f([x]+k/m) is less than e/2. |x-([x]+k/m )| > 1/m so not assure that it less than e, isnt it?

Comment: @user140794 It is thanks to the uniform continuity (if two points are close enough then the values of the function are close enough). This is why $M$ is chosen first. And is going to be true regardless of where $x$ is going to be later thanks to the uniformity.

Comment: um.. by the way, Is using this specific function satisfied hyphothesis sufficient to proving the problem? that's not normal, isnt it?